# Can threadStatus be changed back to 0 after calling it once?

Tags: java, multithreading

Calling any thread more than once throws "**ILLEGAL THREAD STATE EXCEPTION**",but what if we can change threadStatus back to 0(since it would be considered as NEW thread then).Is it possible to do so?

[image]

and also What does it mean "**we hold the lock**"?

Comment: No it is not possible and it is also not necessary. Just create a new Thread. Holding the lock means: you "are" the only thread that is allowed to use a certain resource (in this case a variable).

Comment: what is not possible? Changing threadStatus back to 0 or calling thread twice after changing threadStatus?

Comment: Both. `threadStatus` is private, so you cannot change it. And "calling" a thread twice is therefore also impossible.

Comment: What you **can** do is Submitting Runnables to an Executor. This is a convenient way to "reuse" one (or more) Thread. It's not exactly the same as resetting the Thread state but the closest you get.

Comment: So does the reason why we cant call thread twice is threadStatus itself or some other reason?

Comment: threadStatus is not really the reason, it makes sure, we can't. The reason is: That's the design. A thread has a certain lifecycle. See one of the answers below. I am sure there plenty reasons why it has been designed that way, but I can only speculate since I do not have references to back up my ideas concerning this. My first idea would be to keep complexity managable.

Comment: then what about "we hold the lock?what does that mean?

Comment: Exactly that. The executing Thread has acquired a lock on some resource. Then the resource is protected against access (i.e. change) from other threads. That is as long as you do not release the lock.

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to re-use or re-create a `Thread`, that may be a sign that you should be using a _thread pool_ (e.g., `ExecutorService`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

As per the thread life cycle,there is now way to come back to NEW state. That is the reason you will get ILLEGAL THREAD STATE EXCEPTION", when you call thread.start() twice on the same thread object , because the thread can not go back in NEW state and thread.start() can be executed If thread is in NEW state.

[image: Thread Life Cycle]

I aggree with @Nicolas, If you want to reuse the threads then you can use `Executors` in java.